# PHP running on IIS - time out after 15minutes

Tags: php, iis

I have a php script which creates (in a loop) 20 PDF documents from HTML files.
Each file contains quite a lot of data (pictures) and generally takes about 2 minutes per file. 
It works perfectly, until a timeout seems to occur at around 15minutes.

I am overriding the php.ini file for this script with

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

as a test.

The ini_set command is clearly working as it is overriding the default 30 seconds.

Is there an IIS setting that I don't know about that is killing scripts / threads after around 15minutes?

Any insight gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

set `max_input_time` to 0  also if you are using fastcgi you need to check fastcgi config timeout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis#php-process-recycling-behavior